# How to send discord.py embed using my existing code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was researching how to use embeds for my bot, and I could not find anything that would work with the code I am already using. The code itself (without any commands and functions) is:

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

client.run(TOKEN)
```

If somebody could please help that would be amazing!

P.S. I am a bit of a beginner to Python, so if you could include in your answer how the full code would look, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord

TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

   channel = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.channels, name="Channel-name")
   embed = discord.Embed(title="title", description=f"description", color=0xE9897E)
   await channel.send(embed=embed)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Attributes:

- Empty
- author
- color
- description
- fields
- footer
- image
- provider
- thumbnail
- timestamp
- title
- type
- url
- video

Discord.py documentation: [click here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed)

Comment: Hi there. I tried putting this into my code using a command, but when I ran it it said that 'after' is not defined, namely in the line where it says after.guild.channels. Do you know a fix for this?

Comment: I fix it try it now

Comment: Hmm the code by itself still isn't working, even if I specify the channel it should be in...

Comment: send the message from the console

Comment: Which message sorry?

Comment: I might have to go for the night where I live so I might be silent until the morning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please indicate that my answer is correct